How can a Vue component avoid affecting the styles of slot elements?
I have the following requirement: On the page, there are multiple elements, and when clicked, they redirect to different pages, some of which require login, while others do not.
I have already created a method loginCheck to check the login status, and placed it at the beginning of the click event handler showInfo. When showInfo is triggered, if the user is logged in, the action is allowed; otherwise, an error is thrown and the user is redirected to the login page. However, with this setup, each click event contains the loginCheck method, which feels redundant and not ideal.
Therefore, I want to create a component like this: The elements that previously required login checks will be placed inside the component's slot. When an element inside the slot is clicked, it will trigger the component's click event doCheck. If the user is logged in, the original method showInfo will be called. The component structure is as follows:
component login-check
<script setup>
const doCheck = () => {
  loginCheck(() => {
    callAction();
  })
  callAction();
}


const emit = defineEmits(['action']);
const callAction = () => {
  emit('action');
}

// loginCheck import from other js
const loginCheck = (loginSuccessCall) => {
  let hasLogin = true;
  if (!hasLogin) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('go login')
    }, 200)
    throw new Error('you are not login');
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div @click="doCheck">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

user page
<script setup>
import LoginCheck from "./components/login-check.vue";

const showInfo = () => {
  console.log("Show info");
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="showInfo">show info</button>
    <login-check @action="showInfo" >
      <button type="button">show info</button>
    </login-check>
  </div>
</template>

So far, the component is working well, but in certain scenarios, the component breaks the styles of the original elements inside the slot. For example, the position or size of the elements becomes incorrect. Therefore, I want to know if there is a way to make sure that my component does not affect the styles of the original elements inside the slot.

Maybe the additional wrapper element breaks certain style selectors? It would probably require some more code and/or a repo to debug in order to solve.  However, do you use vue-router? Navigation guards are perfect for this kind of situation. It would address the root problem and avoid the implementation issues of your current solution attempt, if you're willing to change course.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. As said, it could be design problem. In case the problem with nesting is not avoidable, use more specific selectors that prevent this with >, :not, etc

You provided a very good idea! But it doesn't seem to replace the original click event, because you don't know what was done in the original click event, they may be requesting data or some other operations. Not all of them are routing behaviors, and I need to verify the login behavior before the click event is triggered. It is more like a permission management. Vue-router doesn't seem to be able to solve these problems.

I tried replacing the div with a non-existent tag, such as  custom-tag, and it seemed to work fine. Since I don't know much about CSS, I don't know if there will be any unknown side effects of doing this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Can't you just have a click handler on every element, and have a preventDefault within, run logic and continue if user is allowed? Whatever the case, I think it's strange having a slotted login check element as a wrapper. Anyways, before all this,  what protects your routes? You mentioned you're redirecting to different pages. What's stopping the user from manually visiting a page in the browser URL bar? Perhaps this "pre-navigation login check" seems to be pre-emptive optimization, causing you hassle.

You are right. I was in a wrong way of thinking.@Kalnode
